# Laravel 5.5 controller update function issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the update function in the controller where I want to store the values of a form. Here is the code;

```
public function update(Request $request, $id=1){
        $data = array(); 

        $data->firstName = $request->get('firstName');
        $data->lastName  = $request->get('lastName');
        $data->email     = $request->get('email');
        $data->company   = $request->get('company');
        $data->website   = $request->get('website');
        UserAdmin::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update($data);

        //return view('Administrator.profile.profile',$data);
        return redirect('administrator/myprofile');
    }
```

However, after submitting the form, it show me the error;

> **Attempt to assign property of non-object**

Comment: `$data` is array not object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you [can't assign array values with `$data->key`](https://3v4l.org/qvQ7k). An array is not an object and as such has a different syntax.

This wil work however:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id=1){
    $data = array(); 

    $data['firstName'] = $request->get('firstName');
    $data['lastName'] = $request->get('lastName');

    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use an object operator (->) on an array.

For what you are trying to achieve it would be best to use the model to your advantage. By using **findOrFail()** you can return an object.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id=1){

    $data = UserAdmin::findOrFail(Auth::id());
    $data->firstName = $request->get('firstName');
    $data->lastName  = $request->get('lastName');
    $data->email     = $request->get('email');
    $data->company   = $request->get('company');
    $data->website   = $request->get('website');
    $data->save();

    //return view('Administrator.profile.profile',$data);
    return redirect('administrator/myprofile');
}
```

This would achieve what you want but is cleaner. 
Look at the Laravel Eloquent Documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent).